# Use same javascript function for different overlay IDs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display the overlay for different links. 1st overlay has an image and text whereas if we click link2 it must display overlay2 having same structure but diff content. Please help me get the desired output.

```js
function on() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}

function on1() {
  document.getElementById("overlay1").style.display = "block";
}

function off() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.img {
  transition: transform 5s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.25)
}

#overlay,
#overlay1 {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 77777772;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#text,
#text1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20%;
  left: 5%;
  //font-size: 50px;
  color: black;
  //  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  //  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay" onclick="off()">
  <div id="text">
    <div style="width: 48%; float:left">
      <h2>XXX</h2>
      <h4>ZZZ</h4>
      <p style="font-size:14px;">
        Help bring forth the immense talent that resides amongst the valley’s citizens. </p>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 50%; float:right;   margin-top:-220px;
    ">
      <img class="img" style="height:100%" src="http://cdn.dpmag.com/2016/06/boydB3_6881-683x1024.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="padding:20px">
    <h2></h2>
    <a onclick="on()"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="overlay1" onclick="on1()">
    <div id="text1">
      <div style="width: 48%; float:left">
        <h2>AAA</h2>
        <h4>MMM</h4>
        <p style="font-size:14px;">Help bring forth the immense talent that resides amongst the valley’s citizens. </p>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 50%; float:right;   margin-top:-220px;
    ">
        <img class="img" style="height:100%" src="http://cdn.dpmag.com/2016/06/002boydB37683-703x1024.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="padding:20px">
      <h2></h2>
      <a onclick="on1()"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<a onclick="on(id)"style="font-size: 11pt;">Read More -&gt;</a>
<a onclick="on(id)"style="font-size: 11pt;">Read More -&gt;</a>


 1. List item
```

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about this code? Is this a JS problem, a CSS problem, or a HTML problem?

Comment: You may pass id as param `<div id="overlay1" onclick="on1('overlay1')">` and retrieve like so `function on(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}`

Comment: You have 2 `div` with some contents which made up your whole HTML, you've set both of their `display` to `none` which makes the whole `onclick` thing pointless.
If you could explain what you are about to make a little bit better, it would've been possible to fix it.

Comment: Hey, as it's an overlay having content init I had to set it as none; once the user clicks on <a>Read More</a>, the overlay is set back to BLOCK. At the moment Im getting the same overlay upon clicking.

Comment: Give the overlays a common class, like `class="overlay"` and set `display` to `none` for all of them before setting `display` to `block`.

Comment: @Shahjahan This isnt working for me, could you please help me by doing it on https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @PeterKrebs 
Adding class didn't work, I've added a few lines of code and it is giving the same output.

Answer (score 0):

There are **better** ways to achieve this, however as per your requirement you may pass different `ids` &`actions` as `params` to same function like so

```js
function on() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}

function on1() {
  document.getElementById("overlay1").style.display = "block";
}

function off() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
}

function toggle(id, value) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = value;
}
```

```css
.img {
  transition: transform 5s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.25)
}

#overlay,
#overlay1 {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 77777772;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#text,
#text1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20%;
  left: 5%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: black;
  transform: translate(-50% -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50% -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay" onclick="toggle('overlay', 'none')">
  <div id="text">
    <div style="width: 48%; float:left">
      <h2>XXX</h2>
      <h4>ZZZ</h4>
      <p style="font-size:14px;">
        Help bring forth the immense talent that resides amongst the valley’s citizens. </p>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 50%; float:right;   margin-top:-220px;
    ">
      <img class="img" style="height:100%" src="http://cdn.dpmag.com/2016/06/boydB3_6881-683x1024.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="padding:20px">
    <h2></h2>
    <a onclick="toggle('overlay', 'block')"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="overlay1" onclick="toggle('overlay1', 'block')">
    <div id="text1">
      <div style="width: 48%; float:left">
        <h2>AAA</h2>
        <h4>MMM</h4>
        <p style="font-size:14px;">Help bring forth the immense talent that resides amongst the valley’s citizens. </p>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 50%; float:right;   margin-top:-220px;
    ">
        <img class="img" style="height:100%" src="http://cdn.dpmag.com/2016/06/002boydB37683-703x1024.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="padding:20px">
      <h2></h2>
      <a onclick="toggle('overlay1', 'block')"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<a onclick="toggle('overlay', 'block')" style="font-size: 11pt;">Read More -&gt;</a>
<a onclick="toggle('overlay', 'block')" style="font-size: 11pt;">Read More -&gt;</a> 1. List item
```

Comment: Hey @Shahjahan, thanks for your answer but unfortunately it isn't working, seems like its giving the same output; it should display different images and titles.

Comment: You need to change your HTML implementation. This answer serves your requirement `Use same javascript function for different overlay IDs`